# Whats my code is getting crashed as I run it?

Tags: c

This is the program that I've written to enter the details of the students and displays these details through a dedicated function. This program works fine when I tried directly w/o dividing it into a different function.

**Expected outcome:** Run the program -> program asks for input name, rollno and marks -> program displays the same -> exits

**But instead:**  Runs the program - > [Error] cannot convert 'studinfo' to 'studinfo*' for argument '1' to 'void display(studinfo*, int)'

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct studinfo{
        char name[50];
        int roll;
        float marks;
    };

void display(struct studinfo s1[100], int b);

int main()
{

    int a;
    printf("Enter the number of students \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    
    
    

    struct studinfo s[100];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the Name :\n");
        scanf("\n%[^\n]s", s[i].name);
        printf("Enter the roll no. \n");
        scanf("%d", &s[i].roll);
        printf("\n");
        printf("Enter the marks\n");
        scanf("%f", &s[i].marks);
    }
    


display(s[100], a);
    
    return 0;
}
void display(struct studinfo s1[100], int b)
{   
        for(int i = 0; i<b; i++)
    {
            printf("Name: %s\n", s1[i].name);
            printf("Roll no: %d\n", s1[i].roll);
            printf("Marks: %f", s1[i].marks);
            
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your function `display` match with its prototype?

Comment: `display(s[100], a);`? That will call the `display` function passing a single `struct studinfo` object. The compiler should not allow this. So the code you show isn't a proper [mre], so we can't really help you.

Comment: Oh, and you're not getting a crash, you're getting a *build error*. You have to learn the difference between build errors and runtime errors. Remember that creating a C program is a multi-step process: 1) Edit source code; 2) Build source code into executable program; 3) Run program. The error you get is in step 2. I suggest you spend a little more time with your beginners learning material as both that, and the invalid `scanf` format, should be covered.

Answer (score 3):

`display(s[100], a);` tries to call `display` with a single `struct studinfo` object as the first argument (the hundredth `struct studinfo` in the array, which is out of bounds), but `display` is declared to take a pointer to `struct studinfo`s.  Since arrays decay into pointers to their first element, the correct call is therefore:

```
display(s, a);
```

Sidenote: `%[^\n]s` should be `%[^\n]`. `s` is not part of the `%[`...`]` conversion specifier.